# Magento 2 Generate Product Url Keys?

Tags: magento2, product, url-rewrite

We have imported **simple products** into magento 2 without **url_key** earlier. front-end also working fine.

- https://prnt.sc/mia64k

But we would like to generate url_keys for those products.

> **Observations :**

1. While saving product from magento admin end the url_key has been generating and associating to the product. but we have around 1000 products.
2. Tried with programmatically to save the product but not getting expected result.

---

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State'); $state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 
$product_id = 1036;
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$product->save();
echo "Product Saved Successfully ====>".$product_id;
```

How do we overcome this issue.? Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing?

Comment: yes i did. but no luck...